# ember.js, rails, rails-ember, rabl

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, rabl, ember-rails

Getting weird issue with ember.js:

```
TypeError: Object Status has no method 'eachRelatedType'
at DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.configureSideloadMappingForType (http://localhost:5000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:7798:10)
at DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.sideload (http://localhost:5000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:7768:10)
at DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.extractMany (http://localhost:5000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:7692:10)
at superWrapper [as extractMany] (http://localhost:5000/assets/ember.js?body=1:1240:16)
at DS.Adapter.Ember.Object.extend.didFindAll (http://localhost:5000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:8307:16)
at http://localhost:5000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:9894:15
at invokeCallback (http://localhost:5000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9754:19)
at publish (http://localhost:5000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9424:9)
at Promise.publishFulfillment (http://localhost:5000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9844:7)
at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://localhost:5000/assets/ember.js?body=1:5894:24)
```

When my code tries to display a list of statuses:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Status = DS.Model.extend
  body: DS.attr('string')

App.StatusesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
 model: ->
    @get('store').findAll 'Status'

App.Router.map ()->
   @resource 'statuses'

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({ namespace: "api/v1" });

DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", {
  status: "statuses"
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend
 revision: 12
 adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
```

templates:

status.handlebars:

## Entries...

```
{{#each status in controller}}
  {{render "status" status}}
{{/each}}
```

statuses.handlebars:

### {{body}}

Json:

```
{"statuses":[{"id":2,"body":"Test","user_id":3}]}
```

Versions:

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.4.0 ember.js?body=1:3462
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 ember.js?body=1:3462
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
```

Can any one see what I'm doing wrong? really struggling with this one, must be something simple :)

Thanks Heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by update the ember-data libraries to the latest version.